# Why does this code log 'undefined'?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

My package json is configured to use ES6 modules using babel:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/index.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015,stage-2",
    "build": "babel src -d dist",
    "serve": "node dist/index.js"
},
```

This is my index file:

```
import test from './test'
console.log(test)
console.log(test())
```

Test file:

```
let test = () => console.log('test');
export default test;
```

When I run the code, I got:

```
[Function: test]
test
undefined
```

Where does the undefined come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're logging the return value of the function:

```
console.log(test())
```

You first invoke `test` which logs `'test'`. Next, since `console.log` doesn't return anything, `test` doesn't return anything so the return value is `undefined` which is what is logged.

Answer (score 1):

Because test () is not returning any type which you are trying to log in console. i.e why it is displaying undefined in console